# How exactly did Mahito meet Sukuna?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

My understanding of Mahito's technique is that he can reshape souls and thus shapeshift bodies, so how could he meet Sukuna when he touched Yuji's body (in episode 13) and when Yuji jumped into his domain? I don't understand, what did he do?

Answer (score 1):

### Mahito touches Yuji:

When Yuji first ate Sukuna’s finger, Gojo states Yuji “**combined**” or “**merged**” with it. This could likely mean Sukuna’s and Yuji’s souls became one. So when Mahito uses his **Idle Transfiguration cursed technique** to touch Yuji’s soul, he’s also touching Sukuna soul. We can't consider the possibility of **Sukuna overpowers Yuji’s soul** theory, so Yuji wouldn’t be able to have any control of his body whatsoever because Sukuna wouldn’t allow that.

### Yuji enters Mahito's domain:

**Self-Embodiment of Perfection** increases the effectiveness of Mahito's **Idle Transfiguration cursed technique** by allowing him to transfigure the souls of the targets within his domain without requiring physical contact. Nanami described the experience of being inside Mahito's Domain as *akin* to literally being in the palm of Mahito's hand. Alongside **Satoru Gojo's Unlimited Void**, Kento Nanami said Self-Embodiment of Perfection is an almost **guaranteed victory** for the caster.

However, a major drawback of this ability is that Mahito is forced to touch the **souls of everyone inside the domain**, which backfires when Yuji Itadori enters the domain from the outside, causing Mahito to unintentionally touch Sukuna's soul a second time, prompting the King of Curses to lash out at Mahito